# transferring values within elements of $_POST to pre-existing array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, post, mysqli

I have the following associative array stored in a php file also containing a database connect statement.

```
$fields = array(
    "A" => "A",
    "B" => "B",
    "C" => "C",
    ...
);
```

Here I am calling it

```
include('dbconnection.php');
```

What I intended from this code is that the **$field** values within **$_POST[$field]** would be transferred over to values stored within **$fields**.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    //iterating through fields array
    foreach($fields as $column => $field){

        //cleaning and storing user input in fields array 
        $field = mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn , htmlspecialchars($_POST[$field]));
    }
```

These new **$fields** array values would then be transferred over to **$emptyArray**, where elements of the array containing 0, NULL, FALSE, or "" values would be filtered out.

```
    $emptyArray = array();

    $emptyArray = array_merge ($emptyArray, array_values($fields));

    $emptyArray = array_filter($emptyArray);
```

Finally, after checking if there were any elements stored in **$emptyArray**, an error message would be issued, along with a call to run function **renderform**.

```
    if (empty($emptyArray)){    
        $error = 'You have reached this message because you did not specify a field to update';
        renderForm($id, $fields, $error);
    }
}
```

function **renderform** contains the argument **$fields**, the first array in this chain, which is why I chose to use **$emptyArray** instead of **$fields** in order to conserve its structure.

However, if I run print_r of **$fields** and **$emptyArray** immediately before **renderform**, I receive arrays identical to keys and values stored in **$fields** prior to their manipulation

> Array ( [A] => A [B] => B [C] => C [...] => ...)

Can I use $_POST[$field] in the way that I'm intending (**$field** values within **$_POST[$field]** being transferred over to values stored within **$fields**)? If so, is this good practice?

Thanks for reading,
I'm happy to answer any questions.

Comment: Couldn't you just use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a single loop:

```
$fields = array(
    "A" => "A",
    "B" => "B",
    "C" => "C",
);
$post=[];
foreach($fields as $key => $val){
    if(!isset($_POST[$key]) || !$_POST[$key]){
        die("data for $key is incorrect or missing");
    }
    $post[$key] = mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn , htmlspecialchars($_POST[$key]));
}
//all is fine, use $post array for whatever you need it for
```